# Stuck on 2 NullPointerException errors in Java

Tags: java, android, file-io, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to load a list of files into an array and then take those arrays and pull information on a line by line basis from them. I've been trying to figure this out for almost 4 hours now but I don't understand what the NullPointerException error wants me to do. I get the error at the for loop declaration in the initializeLocations method, and in the main when burns.initializeLocations() is called. Any suggestions?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class LocationNode
{
   private String name;
   private String hoursText;
   private String descriptionText;
   //add image for location for info page as an attribute later

public LocationNode(){
    name = "";
    hoursText = "";
    descriptionText = "";
}

//constructor
public LocationNode(String initName, String initHours, String initDescription){
    name = initName;
    hoursText = initHours;
    descriptionText = initDescription;
}

public void setName(String textName){
    name = textName;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setHours(String textHours){
    hoursText = textHours;
}

public String getHours(){
    return hoursText;
}

public void setDescription(String textDescription){
    descriptionText = textDescription;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return descriptionText;
}

public void initializeLocations() throws IOException
{
    File folder = null;
    File[] listOfFiles;

    //creates "path to files" variable
    folder = new File(".Tiger Map App/src/LocationTextFiles"); 

    //creates array of all the files in the folder
    listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) { //runs for loop to "number of files"
        //takes current file in loop iteration and sticks it in a temp file
        File temp = listOfFiles[i]; 
        //checks if file is valid
        if (temp.isFile() && temp.getName().endsWith(".txt")) 
        {
            //takes contents of file and places them into a String(can replace "content" variable w/ array)
            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(temp, "UTF-8"); 

            //test printing if contents are actually pulling from file
            System.out.println(content); 
        }
    }       
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    LocationNode burns = new LocationNode();
    burns.initializeLocations();
}
```

}

Comment: On what line is the error occurring? It must be so that listOfFiles is null!

Comment: Are you sure about this file location: `folder = new File(".Tiger Map App/src/LocationTextFiles");` ?

Comment: The stacktraces with the NPEs you're getting must be showing exactly at which line of the code the problem occurs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//creates "path to files" variable
folder = new File(".Tiger Map App/src/LocationTextFiles"); 

//creates array of all the files in the folder
listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Are you sure that this is the right directory? The second line I've copied here can assign listOfFiles to null if there are no files in that directory or you've specified the directory name incorrectly. Then in your loop

```
listOfFiles.length
```

will result in a null pointer since you're trying to get the length of a null instance.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up moving the folder up one level to the root and it worked

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) most likely '.Tiger Map App/src/LocationTextFiles' is not a folder.

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

listOfFiles could be null. check this is correct `folder = new File(".Tiger Map App/src/LocationTextFiles");` Output the value of listoffiles before the loop and I suspect it will be null, hence the listoffiles.length throws the exception.